# Sublime Text 3 not loading files from current directory into sidebar

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

When using the latest Sublime Text 3, and starting it from a directory with `subl .` , it does no longer open a window with the files from the current directory in the sidebar. Instead the sidebar is empty, and it brings up an empty editor window.

Even re-install did not fix this.

Symptoms:

- running `subl .` hangs, and does not go to the background, empty window
- starting `subl local_directory` has the same effect: empty window
- when trying to start `subl .` multiple times, it does not bring up any new windows
- but when using the menu option "File -> Open" and then selecting the project directory, it opens up a new window and correctly shows the directory contents in the sidebar

To me it looks like the `subl` executable is buggy

On OSX:

```
> shasum `which subl`
19acc6580a3c669375e62e8307878230bffd78ac  /usr/local/bin/subl
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe try `subl folder_name/` ?

Comment: `.` IS the folder name... it is the UNIX shortcut for current directly.
therfore: `subl .`

Comment: Yes I know, but I'm recommending an alternative to try. Normally, it should work with `.` as a current directory.

Comment: i tried `subl local_folder` and it also did not work. I'll update the question